# Не хватает свободного места на диске, как очистить

Tags: ubuntu

`root@20635:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      4.0G  3.9G     0 100% /
udev            236M  4.0K  236M   1% /dev
tmpfs           103M  196K  103M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            257M     0  257M   0% /run/shm`

Как видно /dev/xvda1 заполнен на 100%. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за каталог и чем он засоряется? и как его очистить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вангую что у вас виртуалка. /dev/xvda1 - это не каталог, а диск, который смонтирован как корень вашей файловой системы. Корень - это все каталоги в вашей ФС. Нельзя так просто взять и почистить корень.  Но как чаще всего бывает больше всего места занимает каталог /home/ или каталог /var/log/. Зайдите в каталог выполните `du -sh` увидите суммарный объем каталога, что бы понять, что в этом каталоге самое большое выполните `du -sh *`. Такие поступательные движения позволят вам определить в каком каталоге больше всего пиратского контента)

Comment: Рекомендую https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/baobab/

Comment: @dzhioev baobab выглядит интересно. Я пользуюсь ncdu - такое же, только консольное.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы в интерактивном режиме исследовать расход свободного места на диске, используйте программу `ncdu`. При запуске она считает расход места в текущей директории и всех вложенных (рекурсивно).

Разумеется, чтобы посчитать объем директорий, вам необходим доступ на их чтение. Запускайте с sudo.

```
cd /
sudo ncdu
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

диск всего 4Гб это как-то маловато, система скорее всего занимает не меньше 1Гб. смотри что еще ставил. чтобы посмотреть какие каталоги сколько занимают места используй команду

- du -sh /*
- du -sh /home/*
- и тп